# Matplotlib animation + IPython: temporary disabling interactive mode?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ipython

I have a python a script that generates an animation using matplotlib's `animation.FuncAnimation` and `animation.FFMpegWriter`. It works well, but there's an issue when running the code in IPython: each frame of the animation is displayed on screen while being generated, which slows down the movie generation process.

I've tried issuing `plt.ioff()` before running the animation code, but the figure is still displayed on screen. Is there a way to disable this behavior in IPython?

On a related note, if a run the script from a shell (i.e. `python myMovieGenScript.py`), only one frame is shown, blocking execution. I can close it and the rest of the frames are rendered off screen (which is what I want). Is there a way to prevent that single frame to be displayed, so no user interaction is required?

Comment: what version are you using? That is not the behavior I have observed saving animations (the screen does not update at all during the saving).  Are you forcing a re-draw to screen in your callback?

Comment: You are right! I wasn't forcing a re-draw in my code, but the callback was calling a third-party method that was issuing a plt.show(). That's the culprit. Thanks!

Comment: Could you write that up as an answer? And tell who ever wrote your third-party code to stop doing that.  It would be very helpful if you shown some (simple!) code.

Answer (score 0):

As @tcaswell pointed out, the problem was caused by the callback that was indirectly calling `plt.show()`.